# Apex sharing insert

Tags: apex, sharing, dml, bestpractice, apex-managed-sharing

We are now investigating some performance issues for the client and trying to speed up their processes. One of the time consuming parts is apex sharing that we have there.

I am pretty sure that some time ago I have read that insert of apex shares can happen without any checks on existing ones because SF will make a check internally anyway and that it is possibly even better for performance to "brute force" insert apex shares instead of querying them first to eliminate duplicates.

For example:
There are 10 million Accounts and 20 million AccountShare records in the org. I need to share accounts A1-A20 with public group G. Which of these will be better?

1.

```
List<AccountShare> accShares = new List<AccountShare>();
for (Account a : accs) {
    AccountShare accSh = new AccountShare();
    accSh.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
    accSh.AccountId = a.Id;
    accSh.RowCause = 'Manual';
    accSh.UserOrGroupId = pg.Id;
    accSh.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'None';
    accShares.add(accSh);
}
if (!accShares.isEmpty()) {
    insert accShares;
}
```

2.

```
List<AccountShare> accShares = new List<AccountShare>();
List<AccountShare> existingShares = [SELECT Id, AccountId 
                                     FROM AccountShare 
                                     WHERE AccountId IN :accs 
                                     AND UserOrGroupId = :pg.Id 
                                     AND AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit'];
Set<Id> sharedAccIds = new Set<Id>();
for (AccountShare accSh : existingShares) {
    sharedAccIds.add(accSh.Account);
}
for (Account a : accs) {
    // Only create a share if it does not exist yet
    if (!sharedAccIds.contains(a.Id)) {
        AccountShare accSh = new AccountShare();
        accSh.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
        accSh.AccountId = a.Id;
        accSh.RowCause = 'Manual';
        accSh.UserOrGroupId = pg.Id;
        accSh.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'None';
        accShares.add(accSh);
    }
}
if (!accShares.isEmpty()) {
    insert accShares;
}
```

I am looking for documents that could prove/fail my thoughts about this "brute force" shares insert.

Comment: Did you try both the approaches on large set of data ?

Comment: if you are sharing account records to public groups then why dont you use in a configurable way?